# ¿Cómo guardar una imagen en base de datos MySQL como BLOB con envío por AJAX hacía PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, blob

Estoy intentando guardar imagenes en base de datos, como tipo de dato BLOB aparte de la imagen, se guardan otros campos (date, text, number) anteriormente mandaba las imagenes directo desde el form de la manera:

```
<form id="formulario_registro_pago" action="../models/registrar_pago.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Las imagenes se envía atraves del uso con AJAX, uno toda la información atraves del metodo formData además del uso de append de JQUERY, bueno al momento de mandar a registrar_pago.php hago las validaciones correspondiente y a las imagenes las valido con la superglobal $_FILES

```
if ($_FILES) {
    // Se envío una imagen
} else {
    // No se envio una imagen
}
```

La información de los campos se inserta en una tabla "pagos", las imagenes se insertan a la tabla tickets de la manera siguiente (Bueno primero se valida si se execute() el insert a la tabla pagos con $lastInsertId):

```
if ($lastInsertId != 0) {
    $numeroCombrobante = 1;
    foreach ($_FILES as $comprobantes) {
        $numeralComprobante = $numeroCombrobante ++;
        $nombreImagenComprobante = "$productoCampana $numeroCredito $fechaPago $numeroCombrobante";
        $imagenComprobante = addslashes(file_get_contents($comprobantes['tmp_name']));
        if (!(in_array($comprobantes['type'], $formatoComprobantes)) && $comprobantes['size'] >= $limiteComprobanteKilobytes * 4) {
            $response -> estado = false;
            $response -> mensajeError = '¡Ups! Imagen no válida, solo se puede cargar imágenes con formato .jpg, .jpeg, .png y no mayor a 4 MB';
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            $sentenciaPreparada = $conexionBaseDatos -> prepare(
                "INSERT INTO tickets (nombreTicket, imagenTicket, registroAgente, nombreAgente, numeroTicket, idPago) VALUES (:nombreTicket, :imagenTicket, :registroAgente, :nombreAgente, :numeroTicket, :idPago)"
            );
            $sentenciaPreparada -> bindValue(':nombreTicket', $nombreImagenComprobante, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sentenciaPreparada -> bindValue(':imagenTicket', $imagenComprobante, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sentenciaPreparada -> bindValue(':registroAgente', $usuarioLogueado, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sentenciaPreparada -> bindValue(':nombreAgente', $usuarioNombre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sentenciaPreparada -> bindValue(':numeroTicket', $numeralComprobante, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $sentenciaPreparada -> bindValue(':idPago', $lastInsertId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $sentenciaPreparada -> execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Ahora bien, al momento de generar ambos inserts a las tablas, el insert a la tabla de pagos, funciona bien (me faltan algunas validaciones, al mejor no es el mejor codigo pero funciona), el insert a la tabla de ticket tiene un problema ¿Cuál es? bien inserta todo pero la imagen no la inserta correctamente, genera el insert con:

```
$sentenciaPreparada -> bindValue(':imagenTicket', $imagenComprobante, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Pero lo genera vacío, llena el campo pero no guarda algo, al momento de visualizar la imagen en otra pantall me indica "Parece que el formato de este archivo no es compatible", me imagino que el error está en

```
$imagenComprobante = addslashes(file_get_contents($comprobantes['tmp_name']));
```

¿Alguien tiene una idea para que me pueda ayudar?

Nota: Antes como les decía guardaba todo de la siguiente manera:

```
foreach($_FILES['comprobante_pago']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name){
    // Variable nombreImagenTicket compuesta por variables [$producto_campaniaFormateado] [$numero_creditoFormateado] [$fecha_pagoFormateado] ejemplo P-AVANCE C-21668876 F-2021-11-24
    $numeral_ticket = $numero_ticket ++;
    $nombreImagenTicket = $producto_campania . ' ' . $numero_credito . ' ' . $fecha_pago . ' ' . $numeral_ticket;
    // Numeral Ticket
    // Variable imagenTicket
    $imagen_ticket = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['comprobante_pago' ['tmp_name'][$key]));
    // Sentencia INSERT para insertar la imagen del ticket en tabla "tickets"
    $query_guardar_ticket = "INSERT INTO tickets (nombreTicket, imagenTicket, registroAgente, nombreAgente, numeroTicket, idPago) VALUES ('$nombreImagenTicket', '$imagen_ticket', '$agente_cobranza', '$agente_nombre', '$numeral_ticket', '$last_insert_id')";
    $transaccion_guardar_ticket = mysqli_query($mysqlConexionPB, $query_guardar_ticket);
}
```

Honestamente batalle mucho con lo de los type MIME

```
Array ( [name] => ALIVIO 96829234001201 20221028 1.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php8384.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 97361 )
```

de las imagenes desde un principio, muchos dirán que no busque en otras partes de internet pero si lo hice, una disculpa si no supe explicarme con la pregunta.

Les dejo la imagen de prueba que intento subir al servidor:

[image: Comprobante de pago de prueba]

Comment: Cuando vas a pasar imágenes debes indicarlo con `PDO::PARAM_LOB` ([ver documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php)), prueba a ponerlo así: **`$sentenciaPreparada -> bindValue(':imagenTicket', $imagenComprobante, PDO::PARAM_LOB);`** Si aún así no funciona, entonces verifica que `$imagenComprobante` es una imagen válida, que la tabla está definida con el tipo de dato correcto, etc.

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar, en la tabla esta como "MEDIUMBLOB" el tipo de dato, sigo revisando pero nadamás no

Comment: ¿En `$imagenComprobante` tienes una imagen válida?

Comment: Activa los errores **temporalmente** poniendo esto al principio del script: `ini_set('display_errors', '1');
 ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` Así verás con más detalle el posible error. Si no lo entiendes puedes agregar a la pregunta los mensajes de error que veas pulsando en [edit].

Comment: Pues no me salío ningún error, los estoy revisando en DevTools

Comment: ¿Qué hay sobre la depuración de `$imagenComprobante`? ¿Verificaste **que es una imagen válida**?

Comment: Sí es una imagen válida, son imagenes de comprobantes que subía con la manera anterior del código, estaba revisando algo de base_encode()

Comment: ¿Es válida porque crees que lo es, o porque comprobaste que lo es? ¿De qué modo has verificado que es válida? Intenta mostrarla o descargarla. No interpretes los hechos, debes verificarlos.

Comment: Prueba con `bindParam` en vez de `bindValue`, o sea: **`$sentenciaPreparada -> bindParam(':imagenTicket', $imagenComprobante, PDO::PARAM_LOB);`**

Comment: No funciono tampoco de esa manera, intento visualizar el dato en la base de datos con "Open Value in Editor" al parecer si carga el dato (imagen) pero al intentar verla marca que los datos parecen no ser validos

Answer (score 0):

Mi problema quedo resuelto. Lo solucione quitando el metodo addslashes()

```
$imagenComprobante = addslashes(file_get_contents($comprobantes['tmp_name']));
```

Quedando solo como

```
$imagenComprobante = file_get_contents($comprobantes['tmp_name']);
```

De esa manera empezo a cargar correctamente a la base de datos como tipo de dato MEDIUMBLOB.

Consejos:

1. Es cierto lo del uso de PDO::PARAM_LOB como lo mencionaron en un comentario, para cuando sean datos muy pesados usualmente textos o imagenes, revisa la [documentación
   de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php) para mayor referencia.
2. Es preferible que guardes imagenes, textos, PDF, videos en una carpeta en el directorio de tu aplicación web, no directamente en la tabla todo esto para evitar saturar la misma tabla. (En mi caso la tabla ya no la puedo ni migrar por el peso que tiene de algunos 8K registros, pero requería que siguiera funcionando así)
3. No abusar nunca de los filtros. Si usas consultas preparadas no hace falta que filtres ningún dato

Comment: Falta otra *moraleja*: no abuses nunca de los filtros. Si usas consultas preparadas no hace falta que filtres ningún dato.